# Install Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 7 in a JBOD array

Tags: dual-boot, raid

Some weeks ago I decided to try ubuntu on a Virtual Machine, and I really like it! Then, some days ago, I tried to install it on my computer, together with Windows 7. But, now, I have a problem. My computer have 2 HD's (1Tb and 500Gb) in a JBOD array, and then, 2 partitions: 50gb for Windows 7, and the rest to my files. I've created another 30gb partition to install ubuntu, from the free space on my 2° partition, but, since I'm really new to ubuntu and linux, I really don't know what to do. Ubuntu doesn't recognize the Raid, and I already checked [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto), but, since it's a little old, and I can't loose my files, didn't helped too much, I think.
Some details:
The JBOD is configured on the motherboard controller, and windows is installed just with a special driver, with no programs at all.
RAID Controller vendor is AMD.
This kind of question probably are asked frequently, sorry for that, but I am really new to ubuntu. Also, sorry for my poor english, it isn't my native language.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

There's one of two things going on here:

1. The RAID used in Windows was built by Windows storage manager and is thus software RAID specific to that OS. It is not transferable to other operating systems.
2. The RAID was configured in the BIOS, that's "fake RAID", and you simply haven't identified the proper RAID driver yet for Linux (or it doesn't exist) to be able to assemble the array.

It's up to you to drill down into the details and deploy the proper solution. Ideally, you would use a HW RAID controller that abstracted all this away for you.
Worst case, you use "Fake RAID", which is really just platform independent software RAID, to be able to share the RAID sets between Windows in Linux.

If it were me, and all I had was "Fake RAID", I wouldn't even bother. My data integrity is more important to me then sharing data between two OS. Furthermore, NTFS isn't fully supported on Linux, reading is OK, but if you start writing to that array you can destroy the data.